# How to convert VARCHAR datetime to DATETIME type to populate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, converters

I have a table with a VARCHAR() column with values in this format:

```
2012-10-05T11:14:00-04:00
```

I need to put this data into another table where the data type of the field is DATETIME.

How would I go about converting

```
2012-10-05T11:14:00-04:00
```

to

```
2012-10-05 11:14:00
```

?

I tried:

```
CAST(LEFT(REPLACE(fieldtimestamp, 'T', ' '), 19) AS DATETIME)
```

But it keeps giving me the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select CAST(LEFT(REPLACE('2012-10-05T11:14:00-04:00', 'T', ' '), 19) AS DATETIME)
```

works for me giving

```
2012-10-05 11:14:00.000
```

under sql server 2012

Comment: the double quotes did not have a space in it. that's my bad! thanks! :)

Comment: @Rj. they did on your query

Comment: Be very careful about *removing* the T. That might actually *break* your date/time value depending on `dateformat`/`language` settings. See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Answer (score 7):

This will do:
`SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(fieldtimestamp,19),126)`

No need for replacing the `'T'`.

Comment: +1 it is even a really bad idea to remove the `T` because that makes the conversion dependent on `set dateformat`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Yeah, I think so too. And op isn't using a secure convert by not providing the format explicitely. But, well, that's my opinion

Comment: More [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#YYYYMMDD) on what might happen when using yyyy-mm-dd date format without specifying a format in convert. Using `T` is safe even without a format so your answer is doubly safe :).

Comment: And `SET LANGUAGE` - try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH` and any day > 12. More here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS SQL Server 2008, you can use DATETIMEOFFSET instead of DATETIME and it will work.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @d DATETIMEOFFSET
SELECT @d = '2012-10-05 11:14:00-04:00'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT thedate, CAST( LEFT( REPLACE( thedate, 'T', ' ' ) , 21 ) AS DATETIME )
>   FROM MyTbl1

If you want the seconds you will need to take 21 letters,

```
thedate                     DATETIME
2012-10-05T11:14:00-04:00   2012-10-05 11:14:00
2012-10-05T11:14:00-05:00   2012-10-05 11:14:00
```

Worked fine in **mysql**

Comment: Why does everyone want to replace the T? It's there for a reason!