# I stupidly made a row with dates as VARCHAR, can I still do date based selects on it?

Tags: mysql

So I have a large table that simply cannot be altered without breaking my PHP app.  Stupidly (yes I know), I made a start date and end date as VARCHAR with data stored as '03/04/2013' for example.

Now i need to be able to search to see which rows are currently 'active' meaning which rows have a start date before today AND and end date after today.

Is this at all possible with an SQL query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql). You just need to do on every query ;-)

Comment: check [STR_TO_DATE()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3296730/1029621)

Comment: You can do it, but it will be slow since it can't be indexed.

Comment: Why not simply convert the column back to datetime type. You can change the type of column. Follow solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611407/how-to-convert-varchar-datetime-to-datetime-type-to-populate-table

Comment: @kellax What part of "cannot be altered without breaking my PHP app" was unclear?

Comment: If you column type can't be changed for any reason, I would then suggest to add 2 date columns and use both from now on, then step by step remove any statement accessing you "old columns", so that at some point you can just drop it...

Comment: Only one real and valid solution: Alter the table turning the `varchar` into a `datetime` and then modify the APP accordingly

Comment: I'd consider converting anyway. Your PHP will break, but you can fix it. It's more likely to break even worse in the future if you don't, plus with real date types you'll be able to do fast, indexed searches on start/end dates, something that will probably be important as the database grows. Look at the time spent as penance :)

Comment: You could add datetime columns, and implement a trigger that automatically fills them in from the varchar columns after every insert and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` as follows:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y') < DATE(NOW())
  AND STR_TO_DATE(end, '%d/%m/%Y') > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this will result not only in a loss of performance due to the fact that you have to convert the content of the column but also because you won't allow MySQL to use any potential index in the column

Comment: I did mention that -- in a comment above.

Comment: @Mark, while Barmar answer is technically correct and will get "things done"... As mentioned by him and several other people, it is extremely inefficient and will hurt your application in the long run. I took the time to compile a very detailed answer with how to tackle the problem without breaking your PHP code. Please take a look at it (and the rest of the stackoverflow community, please follow the same advice hehehe).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Thank you so much!  You are correct!  I will  in the long term be migrating my entire application following your advice, however the application is very clunky and large, so for the immediate future Barmar's answer works for now and gets the 'check'  But your answer is ultimatly the way to go and what I will do over the course of the next month.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Action plan to migrate `VARCHAR` columns to `DATE` without breaking the application:

1. Create new indexed `DATE` columns and fill them with the respective values in the `VARCHAR` columns:

   ```
   -- new column
   ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD `NEW_DATE_COLUMN` DATE;    
   -- index
   CREATE INDEX `MY_TABLE_NEW_DATE_IDX` ON MY_TABLE(`NEW_DATE_COLUMN`);
   -- initial values
   UPDATE MY_TABLE 
   SET `NEW_DATE_COLUMN` = STR_TO_DATE(`VARCHAR_DATE`, '%d/%m/%Y')
   WHERE `NEW_DATE_COLUMN` IS NULL;
   ```
2. Create insert / update triggers to cast your `VARCHAR` columns  to `DATE` and update your new `DATE` columns with their respective values:

   ```
   -- triggers
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE TRIGGER `MY_TABLE_VARCHAR_DATE_BI` BEFORE INSERT ON MY_TABLE
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       IF NEW.`NEW_DATE_COLUMN` IS NULL AND NEW.`VARCHAR_DATE` IS NOT NULL THEN
         SET NEW.NEW_DATE_COLUMN = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.`VARCHAR_DATE`, '%d/%m/%Y');
       END IF;
     END;
   //
   CREATE TRIGGER `MY_TABLE_VARCHAR_DATE_BU` BEFORE UPDATE ON MY_TABLE
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       IF NEW.`NEW_DATE_COLUMN` IS NULL AND NEW.`VARCHAR_DATE` IS NOT NULL THEN
         SET NEW.NEW_DATE_COLUMN = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.`VARCHAR_DATE`, '%d/%m/%Y');
       END IF;
     END;
   //
   DELIMITER;
   ```
3. Use the `DATE` columns in your queries:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
   WHERE `NEW_DATE_COLUMN` BETWEEN 
   CURRENT_DATE AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
   ```
4. Take your time and update your application to get ride of places that uses the original `VARCHAR` columns directly, meanwhile nothing will be broken.
5. When you are done remove the triggers and the `VARCHAR` columns:

   ```
   DROP TRIGGER `MY_TABLE_VARCHAR_DATE_BI`;
   DROP TRIGGER `MY_TABLE_VARCHAR_DATE_BU`;

   ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP `VARCHAR_DATE`;
   ```

---

Working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9af444/1).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that.

Try something like this:-

```
select date_format(str_to_date('03/04/2013', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y%m');
```

or may be this:-(*Just a small change with month and days as I am confused with 03 and 04*)

```
select date_format(str_to_date('03/04/2013', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y%m');
```

OR you may also try to convert your column back to date like this:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `column` = str_to_date( `column`, '%d-%m-%Y' );
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this will result not only in a loss of performance due to the fact that you have to convert the content of the column but also because you won't allow MySQL to use any potential index in the column

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `yourColumn` = str_to_date( `yourColumn`, '%d-%m-%Y' );
```

Convert it do date type without losing your data,add minutes or seconds as needed it.IT will be easier in the long run,but if you prefer dabbling in php..

Or create a new column date type from the varchar one.

Comment: This will break his PHP application, which expects the column to be in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.